# When running a simulation with Roe solver, is it possible to get only one of the solutions right?

Tags: numerical-methods, fluid-dynamics

I'm using CFD (Computational fluid dynamics) to solve numerically the shallow water equations.

I'm writing a code based on roe solver, I'm supossed to get two vectors of solutions: one for the water depth ($h$) and the other one for the discharge ($hu$)...But when I compare the numerical solution with the analytical one, it comes that the water depth doesn't match, while the discharge it does match. 
Is there any way that I could have an error with the implementation if I'm able to get one of the two solutions?

Comment: For introduction to Roe solver see (https://perswww.kuleuven.be/~u0016541/Talks/roe.pdf).

Comment: Potentially interesting, but it would be much better to write the PDE problem using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/418542), as well as the numerical method. Then, showing curves where the numerical solution is superposed to the analytical solution could help.